# Datatables shows System Internal Error after I click List all Owner

Tags: spring, datatables, spring-roo, gvnix

This issue occur after I follow the instruction in gvnix_samples petclinic. I try to find some errors but the code seems fine. Please help..

At first my intention is to see the datatables what it looks like but unfortunately I didnt succeed in my setup after I follow the instructions in the given examples in gvnix samples petclinic.

Comment: Could you provide more info about the steps followed? For example, you cloned the repository, then compile-run, pages you visited, etc.

Comment: Hi, I simply follow the given instructions in gvnix samples in github and I also try to run the script clinic.roo in roo shell but the same issue

Comment: Try to clone the repository https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/, then change to dir  quickstart-app and compile-run directly ...

Comment: The same issue, datatables is not working..

Comment: Which version of gvNIX do you use?

Comment: Checked by cloning the GitHub repo and it's working for me .. please provide more info ...

Comment: please give me ur email, I will send the screenshots

Comment: By the way what JRE version did you used?

Comment: You should use the JDK, I used the JDK 1.7.0_75-b13 ...

Comment: Note you should provide the info about your environment, in the running app the steps followed up to the error, etc ...

Comment: My JDK version 7u79 and 8u45

Comment: I use STS IDE v 3.7.0, gvnix 1.4.1,

Comment: and I use Pivotal Server

Comment: O.S.? on the other side, try it on a Roo Shell running from bash (or similar)

Comment: Can you provide the error stack trace?

Comment: Which Tomcat version?

Comment: I'm using pivotal tc server.

Comment: Now the datatables is working I switch to Tomcat 7.